# I created one application I am browsing Image using JSON and viewing in a table bt i want to change the viewing style i.e grid view how it will be?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I created one application called wallpaper in this apps I am browsing Image  using JSON and viewing in a table.

as Code is lik:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cachedCell"];
if (cell == nil){
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"cachedCell"] autorelease];
}


cell.textLabel.text = [photoTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];

cell.text = [photoTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];


NSData *imageData = [photoSmallImageData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

cell.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
   // cell.accessoryType
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
return cell;
   }
```

But i want to change the viewing style i.e grid view i am not able to make d grid view if any1 hv any ideas how to make a grid view pl..help me with code i wil b thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say, you want to create grid of 3xN. It means, you will have N number of cell rows having 3 images per row. Calculate how many images you are receiving from JSON response. According to total number of images, calculate how many cell rows you will need and in cellForRowAtIndexPath method create UIImageView dynamically.